# MS Access LoadFromText collapses object collection

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my MS Access 2013 front-end database I use two separate techniques:

- LoadFromText to upload new or updated database objects
- A collection to persist multiple instances of a form

However when LoadFromText is used, the collection collapses. This is only an issue when first opening the database, as the typical sequence is:

1. Validate the user
2. Re-link to back end data
3. Use LoadFromText to update any new objects
4. Open a 'dashboard' form as a new instance

If there is nothing to update, LoadFromText is not called, and that's fine. But when there has been an update, the dashboard form disappears as soon as it is opened because the collection has been corrupted somehow.

I have read up about LoadFromText and using a collection to support multiple instances of a form, but cannot find anything that links these issues. Any help or pointers to clarify what's happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's my firm impression that *LoadFromText* is intended to be a developers tool only for retrieving objects from a source control system - if for nothing else, because the frontend will not be compiled after adding forms with code-behind this way.

It may be much simpler just to retrieve a new copy of the frontend from a network folder whenever the user launches the application by clicking a shortcut.

An example script that also works in a Citrix environment can be found here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://rdsrc.us/a8Ws4i)

Comment: That's a fair point but I have found it very useful for on-the-run updates for users. Updates happen every week and users can obtain the new objects as they log in, hardly noticeable to the user but avoids copying a whole 25MB front end file. Also this enables different users to have their own 'profile' (Sales, Finance etc) without having to maintain many versions of the front end. I do call _DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompileAllModules_ after the _LoadFromText_ process.

Comment: Oh, I see, that a somewhat different scenario. But I don't know what could solve your problem, except you could try importing the true objects from a masterdatabase; that should not could kill the collection.

Comment: I've tried using a Scripting Runtime Dictionary to hold the objects but that fails too after _LoadFromText_. My workaround is to use an array of multiple-instance forms, rather more work to maintain but it seems to survive.